# Добавление новой записи несмотря на Update on duplicate key и UNIQUE INDEX

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

Есть следующая таблица (с названием `table0`):

```
id : integer, autoincrement, primary key
table1_id : integer, nullable, foreign key -> table1(id), on delete = cascade, on update = cascade
table2_id : integer, nullable, foreign key -> table2(id), on delete = cascade, on update = cascade
table3_id : integer, nullable, foreign key -> table3(id), on delete = cascade, on update = cascade
smth_field : string
```

По своей сути таблица является промежуточной для связи "многие-ко-многим". Создал UNIQUE INDEX `table_unique_constraint (table1_id, table2_id, table3_id)`.

Пытаюсь сделать:

```
INSERT INTO `table0` (`table1_id`,`table2_id`,`table3_id`,`smth_field`) 
VALUES (NULL,54069,3240349,'2') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE table1_id=VALUES('table1_id'), table2_id('table2_id'), table3_id = VALUES('table3_id'), smth_field = VALUES('smth_field');
```

**Ожидание:**
Обновление записи с такими же `table1_id`, `table2_id`, `table3_id` на ту, что передал в запросе (по сути обновление поле `smth_field`).

**Реальность:**
Добавление новой записи несмотря на то, что стоит уникальный индекс.
Все запросы к СУБД по созданию таблиц и добавлению данных делаю через ***Sequelize***.

Подскажите, в чём дело и как это исправить?

Comment: NULL - не дубликат!!! ибо `NULL <> NULL`.

Comment: @Akina, скажите пожалуйста, как мне обойти тогда это

Comment: Добавить в структуру динамически вычисляемые поля COALESCE(tableX_id,0), и строить уникальный индекс по ним. При этом гарантировать отсутствие подменного значения в реферальной таблице (например, триггером).

Comment: @Akina, если оформите в виде отдельного ответа, то засчитаю его правильным, спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Внешние ключи допускают NULL в значениях NULLable полей. Однако такие значения не являются дубликатами, ибо один NULL не равен другому NULL.

Решением может быть введение в структуру дополнительных вычисляемых полей и создание уникального индекса по ним, а не по исходным полям. При этом значение дополнительных полей (которые можно сделать как хранимыми, так и динамически вычисляемыми - во втором случае они не требуют дополнительного дискового пространства) вычисляется выражением

```
COALESCE(fieldname, constant)
```

где:
 
*fieldname* - имя поля
*constant* - замещающая значение NULL константа

При этом следует гарантировать, что значение-заместитель отсутствует в таблице, на которую ссылается поле. Это можно сделать, например, триггером, запрещающим вставку такого значения.

Для поля, которое ссылается на поле-автоинкремент, удобным значением-заместителем является значение 0. В автоинкрементное поле нельзя вставить ноль, он, как и NULL, вызывает генерацию следующего значения. Соответственно и в триггере потребности нет.